# Can't log in to SSH on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, ssh

On an existing CentOS 7 server, I am unable to log in to SSH with a newly added user account. Although the password is correct, the connection is immediately terminated.

The following PAM error is logged in `/var/log/secure`:

```
Aug 17 12:01:24 server sshd[10972]: Accepted password for testaccount from 1.2.3.4 port 58648 ssh2
Aug 17 12:01:24 server sshd[10972]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user testaccount by (uid=0)
Aug 17 12:01:24 server sshd[10972]: error: PAM: pam_open_session(): Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session
```

The testaccount user has `/bin/bash` as its shell:

```
[root@server /]# grep testaccount /etc/passwd
testaccount:x:10009:10009::/home/testaccount:/bin/bash
```

SSH access via root is working ok.

Output of `ls -ld / /home /home/testaccount`:

```
dr-xr-xr-x. 17 root        root        4096 Jan  4  2017 /
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root        root          48 Aug 17 12:04 /home
drwx------   2 testaccount testaccount   59 Aug 17 12:04 /home/testaccount
```

Output of `date; date --utc`:

```
Thu Aug 17 14:34:02 EDT 2017
Thu Aug 17 18:34:02 UTC 2017
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I've seen this before on a host where PAM was used for integration with Active Directory; if this is the case here, check the time on the servers on both sides of that transaction.

Comment: Active Directory isn't being used - it's a standalone server. I synced the clock earlier just to make sure, but it didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Is SELinux enabled?  Maybe it's getting in the way.  Is the user able to log into the host locally (e. g. via `su`) to isolate SSH as the problem?

Comment: SELinux is disabled (result of sestatus command = SELinux status: disabled). When I try to su to the account from root, it comes back with the same error as in the original post: `su: cannot open session: Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session`

Comment: At least we now know that SSH is not the problem.

Comment: Added output of `ls -ld / /home /home/testaccount` to question.

Comment: Log in as root, then `ssh testuser@localhost`. Does that work? If so, you've probably got a date/time mismatch between your client and this server.

Comment: Please then update your question to include answers to - What time is it right now? - What timezone (or area) are you in? - What does `date; date --utc` tell you on both your client and server?

Comment: Already tried the `ssh testuser@localhost` in a previous comment - that was unsuccessful with the same error.  Adding output of date commands to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Solved - we found the following line in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` which was making the connection terminate for users with UID >= 1000:

```
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
```

Adjusting the account's UID to <1000 resolved the issue. This can be done with the following command:

```
usermod -u 346 testaccount
```